# cannot find symbol variable R in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

```
public class home extends Fragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments

        postlist = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.postList);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                gson = new Gson();
                list = (List) gson.fromJson(s, List.class);
                postTitle = new String[list.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
                    mapPost = (Map<String, Object>) list.get(i);
                    mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
                    postTitle[i] = (String) mapTitle.get("rendered");
                }
                **postlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, postTitle));//R is not Resolved**
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyerror) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("Home");
    }
}
```

I am getting error: cannot find symbol variable R. How to Resolve it.
The same code is running good in activity but creating error when using it in activity.

Comment: Calling `getView()` inside `onCreateView()` view will result in NPE for obvious reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to bind your controls in fragment

```
 @Nullable
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

 postlist = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.postList);

  // your allll code
  return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Problem With line: postlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, postTitle));   R is not resolved

Answer (score 1):

Just happened the same thing to me.
I tried to refer to the rootView as suggested but the error remains.
I tried Build->clean & rebuild but the error remains.

I eventually ended up **deleting my fragment and the layout** corresponding, and then **recreated a new Fragment through the android Studio interface** (New=>Fragment=>Fragment(Blank)), and implemented the exact same code than before, and it worked fine.

I know, it's not the solution that you might be looking for but after spending too much time trying all the suggestions I found online it's the only way that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
View rootView
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (rootView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {

    }



return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Problem is with Array adapter line :postlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, postTitle));  error:cannot find R variable in Fragment.

Comment: One time clean your project or rebuild your project

Comment: try ot add       **import YOURPACKEGENAME.home.R;**

Answer (score 0):

Check for android.R in your imports and remove it.

Android Studio adds it sometimes when converting java code to Kotlin.